# For an n-digit 2's complement binary number (n>1), what is the number of negative integers (as a function of n)?

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, binary

> For an n-digit 2's complement binary number (n>1), what is the number
>   of negative integers (as a function of n)?

So my solution is 2^n but I don't think it's correct.

For example let's say we have a 4-digit 2's complement binary number: 1000.
The 1 in the most significant digit's place indicates the number is negative, so we can only rearrange the 3 digits after that to indicate the number of negative integers, which would be:

1000
1100
1110
1111
1101
1001
1011
1010

So 2^n = 2^4 = 8 different negative integers. 
But I'm confused because this solution doesn't work if the 0 is in the most significant digit's place (i.e. 0001), in which case there are zero negative integers.

Any help is appreciated,

thanks in advance.

Comment: 4-digit 2C numbers can be between -8 to +7. This means 8 negative numbers, 0 and 7 positive numbers. 5-digit 2C numbers are between -16 to +15. This means 16 negative numbers,0 and 15 positive numbers. So negative numbers are 2^(n-1)

Comment: Ah, my math is wrong and I incorrectly did 2^4 = 8. Also I should have looked at the full range of numbers for 4-digit 2's complement. Thanks!!